# PHP Syllable Detection

Tags: php, nlp

I would like to find a way to be able to split a word into syllables with PHP. For example, the word "nevermore" ran through detect_syllables(), would return "nev-er-more." Are there any good APIs or something out there?

Comment: I'm not sure about a native PHP one but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271918/ruby-count-syllables from the related questions has some good guidelines on writing a function to do it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a useful [PHd thesis paper by Frank Liang](http://www.tug.org/docs/liang/) that describes an exceptionally accurate algorithm for this: written over 25 years ago, it's still valid. But I'm not aware of any implementation in PHP

**EDIT**

A quick google has identified this link to a [Text Statistics library](https://github.com/DaveChild/Text-Statistics) in PHP, which includes algorithms for syllable counting within words (among other readability measuring algorithms). You should be able to find the code for syllable splitting here.

Comment: From what I understand that only has a functon for counting the syllable, not actually splitting it.

Comment: While I haven't looked at the actual code: if it can count the syllables, it must be splitting words into sylables to do that count, so the logic must be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I'm actually in the finishing stages of making a PHP Hyphenator class based upon Frank Liang's algorithm and the TeX dictionaries, which pretty much seems to be the appoach taken by all office suites. (Actually I found this topic while looking for a good name for it that wasn't already taken). With slowly improving support from browsers for the ­ entity, it's becoming a realistic option to hyphenate content in websites.

Core functionality is working; splitting (and thus counting) and/or hyphenating text and/or HTML, parsing TeX hyphen dictionaries, caching those parsed dictionaries. Some planned features are still missing but nothing that stops you from using it. Also there's no good documentation, samples, formal unittest or vanity site yet.

I've created a github site for it [here](https://github.com/vanderlee/phpSyllable) and will post the current version on it ASAP, so check back in a few days.

I've only tested it with Dutch (my native language) and US English, so it may still have some issues with languages using different character sets.

Comment: Nice!  That's awesome. I'll check back

Comment: @martijn-van-der-lee - have a look at https://github.com/heiglandreas/Org_Heigl_Hyphenator - Perhaps we can join forces ;)

Answer (score 2):

Note that Frank Liang's paper is on hyphenation, NOT on syllable detection. In addition, his thesis paper itself states that its success rate is around 89% for the dictionary he used, which is not going to be good enough for everyone. There really is no substitute for manually doing it for every single word it seems. It's not that efficient to have to require a complete one-to-one lookup table wordlist in order to do it, but these days storage space is far less expensive than CPU time anyways.

Perhaps someone might consider making a CAPTCHA-like service so that many users could be asked to provide the solution to every known word, with the results checked against each other, so that one person wouldn't have to do it all themselves. I'd hope the results would be released freely once complete.

Comment: The thesis of Frank Liang is the basis of the TeSX-Hyphenation-patterns and one of the points of Liang is, that the automatically created patterns have to be extended to create a better success-rate. This has been done with the TeX-Hyphenation-Patterns. There are other pattern or dictionary-based algorithms out there, but they are not open-source (DIHYPH for example)