# Strings & Arrays, and referring to elements in these

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to split words up so I can count the syllable in each one, but i can't seem to isolate the words at the moment, i can only count the whole number of syllables in the sentence,

```
        var text = $(this).val();
        var words = new Array(text.replace(/\s/g, ' ').split(' '));
        function countSyllables(words) {
            word = words.toString();
            var lWords = word.toLowerCase();
            var wordsArray=lWords.split(",");
            for (var z = 0; z < lWords.length; z++) {
                console.log(wordsArray, "- array of words");
                console.log(wordsArray[z], "- one item[z]");
```

My problem seems to be that i have to convert the array to a string to lower it, but then i can't refer to each individual word, in both cases, to count the syllables:

```
[16:04:02.726] ["this", "is", "test", "text", "", "the", "words", "need", "to", "be", "separately", "analysed.", "hello"] - array of words    
[16:04:02.726] o - one item[z]
```

This is the last character, when i want to refer to the word

I'm sure it's a simple solution but i can't wrap my head around it

Comment: You don't need to specify an `Array()` for `words`, since `split()` will *always* return an array. But why are you replacing a single white-space with a single white-space (are people using tabs or something?) and *then* splitting on that single white-space? Why not simply `split(/\s/)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compute number of syllables in a word in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686483/how-to-compute-number-of-syllables-in-a-word-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong on many levels:

```
var words = new Array(text.replace(/\s/g, ' ').split(' '));
```

What you're after is, AFAIK, something like this:

```
var words = text.split(/[^a-z0-9\-]+/gi);
```

This splits the string, using all white-space, dots, brackets and other punctuation-things as delimiters. I've excluded the dash (`-`), to avoid counting words like `ice-cream` as two words. If you don't care about that, or if you feel that the result is more reliable when you *do* treat dashes as delimiters, just leave them out:

```
var words = text.split(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi);
console.log(text + ' is approx. ' + words.length + ' words long');
```

On the converting to lower-case thing: why not convert the entire text to lower-case from the off?

```
var words = text.toLowerCase().split(/[^a-z0-9\-]+/gi);
```

Oh, and the output of this code does not leave you with empty strings in the array:

```
'Foo... bar, Foobar and lorum ipsorum'.toLowerCase().split(/[^a-z0-9\-]+/gi);
//output: ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "and", "lorum", "ipsorum"]
//length returns 6, which I think is correct
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, was using lwords, but was printing wordsArray!, changed them all to wordsArray now