# JavaScript Syllable Counter - Counting Per Line

Tags: javascript, nlp

## Current

I’ve re-worked [this syllable counter script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686483/how-to-compute-number-of-syllables-in-a-word-in-javascript/8843915#8843915) to:

- Get the value of textarea 1.
- Count the number of syllables in textarea 1.
- Display the results in textarea 2.
- Update the count every time the value of textarea 1 is edited.
- Act as a function (be able to run in multiple instances if wanted).

### Example function of current code

Input *(Textarea 1)*

```
i would appreciate
any help
at all
```

Results *(Textarea 2)*

```
11
```

### Current code

[Here is the existing code as a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gregabbott/5Zwkq/14/).

---

## Goal

I would like this script to:

- Count the syllables of textarea 1 on a per line basis: presumably by splitting the textarea 1 value where there are line breaks e.g. `.split('\n');`.
- Output the results, showing the total number of syllables counted per line.

### Example function of desired code

Input *(Textarea 1)*

```
i would appreciate
any help
at all
```

Results *(Textarea 2)*

```
6
3
2
```

## Problem

I’m quite stuck as to how to do this and would really appreciate any help or JSFiddle showing how to work with the existing code to achieve this.

---

### Notes

For anyone who may be interested using in the syllable count function code itself: it’s not 100% accurate and fails on some words but gives a good general idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it's what you needed.

Callouts:

I created an array that spits the lines up stores them `var arrayOfLines = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").val().match(/[^\r\n]+/g);`.

Then loop through that array and do exactly what you did before, but on each array entry. Then store the results in tempArr, and display the tempArr results.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zwkq/19/)

```
function $count_how_many_syllables($input) {
    $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").keyup(function () {

    var arrayOfLines = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").val().match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
    var tempArr = [];
    var $content;
    var word;
    var $syllable_count;
    var $result;

    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++){
        $content = arrayOfLines[i];
        word = $content;
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        if (word.length <= 3) {
            word = 1;
        }
        if (word.length === 0) {
           return 0;
        }
        word = word.replace(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '')
            .replace(/^y/, '')
            .match(/[aeiouy]{1,2}/g).length;
        $syllable_count = word;
        $result = $syllable_count;
        tempArr.push($result);
    }

    $("[name=set_" + $input + "_syllable_count]").val(tempArr);

    });
}

(function($) {
    $count_how_many_syllables("a");
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much! I really appreciate it!