# RegEx: Understanding Syllable Counter Code

Tags: javascript, regex, encryption

I have used [Dylan's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686483/how-to-compute-number-of-syllables-in-a-word-in-javascript) on here regarding JavaScript syllable counting, and more specifically [artfulhacker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843915), in my own code and, regardless of which single or multi word string I feed it, the function is always able to correctly count the number of syllables.

I have a limited experience with RegEx and not enough prior knowledge to decipher what exactly is happening in the following code without some help. I'm not someone who is ever happy with having some code I pulled from somewhere just work without me knowing *how* it works. Is someone able to please articulate what is happening in the `new_count(word)` function below and help me decipher the use of RegEx and how it is that the function is able to correctly count syllables? Many

```
function new_count(word) {
  word = word.toLowerCase();                                     //word.downcase!
  if(word.length <= 3) { return 1; }                             //return 1 if word.length <= 3
  word = word.replace(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '');   //word.sub!(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '')
  word = word.replace(/^y/, '');                                 //word.sub!(/^y/, '')
  return word.match(/[aeiouy]{1,2}/g).length;                    //word.scan(/[aeiouy]{1,2}/).size
}
```

Comment: I'm here for the exact same reason lol. RegEx is super confusing to me right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I see it, we basically want to count the vowels, or vowel pairs, with some special cases. Let's start by the last line, which does that, i.e. count vowels and pairs:

```
return word.match(/[aeiouy]{1,2}/g).length;
```

This will match any vowel, or vowel pair. `[...]` means a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), i.e. that if we go through the string character-by-character, we have a match, if the actual character is one of those. `{1, 2}` is the number of [repetitions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), i.e. it means that we should match exactly one or two such characters.

The other two lines are for special cases.

```
word = word.replace(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '');
```

This line will remove 'syllables' from the end of the word, which are either:

- **X**es (where **X** is anything but any of '*laeiouy*', e.g. '*zes*')
- *ed*
- **X**e (where **X** is anything but any of '*laeiouy*', e.g. '*xe*')

(*I'm not really sure what the grammatical meaning behind this is, but I guess, that 'syllables' at the end of the word, like '-ed', '-ded', '-xed' etc. don't really count as such.*)
As for the regexp part: `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). I guess it's not really important in this case that this group be *non-capturing*; this just means that we would like to group the whole expression, but then we do not need to refer back to it. However, we could have used a capturing group too (i.e. `(...)` )

The `[^...]` is a negated character class. It means, match any character, which is none of those listed here. (Compare to the (non-negated) character-class mentioned above.)
The pipe symbol, i.e. `|`, is the [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) operator, which means, that any of the expressions can match.
Finally, the `$` anchor matches the [end of the line](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), or string (depending on the context).

```
word = word.replace(/^y/, '');
```

This line removes 'y'-s from the beginning of words (probably 'y' at the beginning does not count as a syllable -- which makes sense in my opinion).
`^` is the anchor for matching [the beginning of the line](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), or string (c.f. `$` mentioned above).

Note: the algorithm only works if `word` really contains one single word.

Answer (score 3):

```
/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/
```

That matches three possible substrings: a letter other than 'l' or a vowel followed by 'es' (like "res" or "tes"); 'ed'; or a non-vowel, non-'l' followed by just an 'e'. Those patterns must appear at the end of the word to match because of the `$` at the end of the pattern. The grouping `(?:  )` is just a grouping; the leading `?:` makes that distinction. The pattern could have been a little shorter:

```
/(?:[^laeiouy]es?|ed)$/
```

would do the same thing. In any case, if the pattern matches the characters involved are removed from the word.

Then,

```
/^y/
```

matches a 'y' at the beginning of a word. If a 'y' is found, it's removed.

Finally,

```
/[aeiouy]{1,2}/g
```

matches any one- or two-character stretch of vowels (including 'y').  The `g` suffix makes it a *global* match, so that the return value is an array consisting of all such spans of vowels. The length of that returned array is the number of syllables (according to this technique).

Note that the words "poem" and "lion" would be reported as one-syllable words, which may be correct for some English variants but not all.

[Here is a pretty good reference for JavaScript regular expression operators.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Likewise it will miss on many plural forms that have a syllabic '-es', like 'dishes' or "cheeses", and there are words on which it will report higher counts than is accurate. too ("sales" => 2). It would only be appropriate in contexts where accuracy isn't very important.

Comment: @Semicolon maybe the goal is to treat "cheeses" as just "cheese"; like, maybe the goal is to get the syllable count for the root ("stem"?) word.