# Java Regex for counting syllables

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a regex pattern to count all the syllables in a word but I'm having trouble ignoring the case when an "e" is alone at the end of the word.

My pattern right now is:

```
[aeiouy]+[^$e]
```

I have given certain rules that are not completely precise but I need to do it that way for the exercise, the rules are the following:

A syllable is a contiguous sequence of vowels, except for a lonely vowel "e" at the end, vowels are "aeiouy", for example the word "sentence" should be only 2 syllables but my pattern is counting 3, the word "there" should be only one syllable by my pattern is counting 2.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: With Yassin example I've noticed that the main issue is that when "e" is following by another character, question marks, comma, etc. The regex is counting another syllable

Comment: It gives me two personnally. Could you provide a demo on Regex101 for example?

Comment: You are right, sentence is giving me two syllables, the problem is that in the test text I have the word "sentence," with a comma at the end and thats why e, is counting as a syllable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx: Understanding Syllable Counter Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384718/regex-understanding-syllable-counter-code)

Comment: `[^$e]` means "any character other than a lowercase 'e' or a dollar sign."  Inside square brackets, `$` has no special meaning whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

As you're having problems with "e" ending words and followed by points or commas etc.

Here is a solution using a 12 syllables sentence.

We are excluding the "e" letter followed by any of the characters below.

---

### Solution

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[aeiouy]+[^$e(,.:;!?)]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("This is a sentence:this is another sentence.");

int syllables = 0;
while (m.find()){
    syllables++;
}
System.out.println(syllables);
```

### Output

```
12
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I've tried but now I'm having trouble with actual syllables following by points, commas, etc. For example "many?" should be 2 but is counting one.